# Outlook add-in works prior to Outlook 2016

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, add-in, outlook-2016, primary-interop-assembly

I've checked other Stackoverflow questions, but no help there.

Running VS2015 C# project for Outlook Add-in. The Add-in appears for Outlook 2010 and prior versions. On Outlook 2016 it just doesn't show up, no errors. It is a COM Add-in, there is no Primary Interop Assembly for Office 2016 yet, could this cause the error?

In Outlook 2010 and prior, under the Outlook File -> Options -> Add-Ins, the add-in is listed, but under Outlook 2016 it does not appear, and i am unable to add the same dll.

Could this be a version problem, or am i missing something else, been at it for a while and tried everything i can think of.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since Embedded Interop Types got created, I wouldn't necessarily expect a PIA for Outlook 2016 to ever appear.

Answer (score 0):

> In Outlook 2010 and prior, under the Outlook File -> Options -> Add-Ins, the add-in is listed, but under Outlook 2016 it does not appear, and i am unable to add the same dll.

Looks like the required windows registry keys were not added. Read more about them in the following articles:

- [Registry Entries for VSTO Add-ins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386106.aspx)
- [Registry Entries for Application-Level Add-Ins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386106(v=vs.90).aspx)

I'd recommend creating an installer for that. See [Deploying an Office Solution by Using Windows Installer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx).

Microsoft Office applications can run solutions created by using versions of Visual Studio prior to Visual Studio 2015. In some cases, these solutions require different versions of the Visual Studio Tools for Office runtime. Different versions of the Visual Studio Tools for Office runtime can be installed side-by-side on the same computer. See [Running Solutions in Different Versions of Microsoft Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772080.aspx) for more information.